# JavaScript выполнить действие после перехода по ссылке

Tags: javascript

Я новичек в JavaScript-е, мне необходимо выполнить действие после перехода по ссылке.
К примеру имеем две страницы A и B
На странице A я выполняю JavaScript действие (заполнения текствого поля и клик по кнопке) происходит переход на странцу B. Здесь тоже необходимо выполнить какое нибудь JavaScript действие, например клик по ссылке.
Вот пример который работает только на странице A, когда происходит переход остальная часть кода как будто бы стирается, это не факт, а мои мои догадки

```
document.getElementById('story').value='Титаник';
document.querySelector('body > div.wrapper > div.header > div.header44 > div.search_panel > span > form > button').click();
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].click();
```

Или другой пример
Переходим по ссылке и там заполняем поле, что тоже не работает

```
window.location.href='http://www.ganjawars.ru/login.php'
function F() {
document.getElementsByName('login')[0].value = 'login';
document.getElementsByName('pass')[0].value = 'password';
}
 onload= F ()
```

Как выполнить действие после перехода по ссылке?

Comment: Это не догадки, а факт: новая страница - новые скрипты (или их отсутствие)

Comment: никак нельзя? после перехода по ссылке выполнить действие?

Comment: Можно сохранить какие-то данные в сторидж. Ну например то что записано в инпут и на другой странице достать это значение и использовать

Comment: А как сохранить данные в сторидж? Не могли бы Вы показать пример?

Comment: По сути sessionStorage или localStorage  это объект. 
И записывает ключ: значение.

Comment: button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  sessionStorage.userName = document.querySelector('.class-input’).value;

});

Comment: И так же его получить уже на другой странице, по ключу (userName).
const userName = document.querySelector('.user-name');
userName.textContent = sessionStorage.userName;

Comment: Евгений Колмак, вы предложили на странице А сохранить данные в сторидж, а на странице Б его получить? Но ведь на странице B, мне нужно будет заново запустить скрипт? Мне бы передать не данные с одной страницы в другую, а скрипт. Чтобы скрипт выполнился на другую страницу. Можно ли это сделать используя storage?

Comment: Страница читается сверху вниз. Скрипты выполняются так же

Comment: После перехода по ссылке. Переходите на тот же домен? Бэковая часть есть?